# Sort binary tree elements into lists in Prolog?

Tags: list, sorting, prolog, binary-tree

I'm attempting to sort a binary tree into 3 lists, one for positive numbers, one for negative numbers, and one for anything else.

I've got this code successfully converting the tree into a list:

```
treePosNeg(void, []).
treePosNeg(tree(Left,Root,Right),[Root|List]) :-
    treePosNeg(Left,List1),
    treePosNeg(Right,List2),
    append(List1,List2,List).
```

Input:

```
treePosNeg(tree(tree(void,a,void),-10,tree(void,b,void)),List).
```

Output:

```
List = [-10, a, b]
```

My logic to sort them was simply checking if Root >= 0, Root < 0, else it goes into the other list. I was attempting to use three predicates of treePosNeg with each checking for their specific type.

```
treePosNeg(void, []).
treePosNeg(tree(Left,Root,Right),[Root|Pos],Neg,Other) :-
    Root >= 0,
    treePosNeg(Left,List1),
    treePosNeg(Right,List2),
    append(List1,List2,Pos).


treePosNeg(tree(Left,Root,Right),Pos,[Root|Neg],Other) :-
    Root < 0,
    treePosNeg(Left,List1),
    treePosNeg(Right,List2),
    append(List1,List2,Neg).

treePosNeg(tree(Left,Root,Right),Pos,Neg,[Root|Other]) :-
    treePosNeg(Left,List1),
    treePosNeg(Right,List2),
    append(List1,List2,Other).
```

But I'm simply getting no as my output. I think the issue is that it's still recursively calling treePosNeg before appending, but of course you need the List1 and List2 elements to be instantiated before being able to use them. I'm still very new to Prolog so please bear with my inexperience!

Comment: You need to be mindful of how many arguments you are using for `treePosNeg`. Sometimes you have 2, and sometimes 4. These are different predicates in Prolog This isn't necessarily a wrong thing to do, but it doesn't look like you did it with design intent. And what do you mean by "sort"? Sorted in what way? Why `Root > 10`? What's special about 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd not bother with the 2-argument version and just stick with 4. In your solution, you're losing a lot of cases due to oversimplification. For example, here:

```
treePosNeg(tree(Left,Root,Right),[Root|Pos],Neg,Other) :-
    Root >= 0,
    treePosNeg(Left,List1),
    treePosNeg(Right,List2),
    append(List1,List2,Pos).
```

Your simplifying down to treePosNeg/2 and appending everything to `Pos`. This doesn't take care of the case where there are negative or non-numeric members in the `Left` and `Right` trees.

Here is a naive/transparent solution that should be pretty clear. Improvements could be made (e.g., to avoid the choice point that is left, for example).

```
% tree_pos_neg(Tree, Pos, Neg, Other)

% A void tree    
tree_pos_neg(void, [], [], []).

% A tree where the head node is positive
tree_pos_neg(tree(L, V, R), [V|Pos], Neg, Other) :-
    number(V),
    V >= 0,
    subtrees_pos_neg(L, R, Pos, Neg, Other).

% A tree where the head node is negative
tree_pos_neg(tree(L, V, R), Pos, [V|Neg], Other) :-
    number(V),
    V < 0,
    subtrees_pos_neg(L, R, Pos, Neg, Other).

% A tree where the head node is neither a positive nor a negative number
%   (it could be *anything* else)
tree_pos_neg(tree(L, V, R), Pos, Neg, [V|Other]) :-
    \+ number(V),
    subtrees_pos_neg(L, R, Pos, Neg, Other).

subtrees_pos_neg(L, R, Pos, Neg, Other) :-
    tree_pos_neg(L, LP, LN, LO),
    tree_pos_neg(R, RP, RN, RO),
    append(LP, RP, Pos),
    append(LN, RN, Neg),
    append(LO, RO, Other).
```

Running this query, you get:

```
| ?- tree_pos_neg(tree(tree(void,a,void),-10,tree(void,b,void)), P, N, O).

N = [-10]
O = [a,b]
P = [] ? ;

no
| ?-
```

---

I just noticed your definition of positive changed to meaning really non-negative, so I updated my answer accordingly.